# Are there research estimates of Capitalistic terror?

Tags: capitalism

In this [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/26147/44102) there is an estimation of communist terror in different countries. And there is a huge amount of work and estimation [related to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_killings_under_communist_regimes). Looks like that this work is actively sponsored by various foundations [like this](https://victimsofcommunism.org/).

Meanwhile, examples of Capitalistic terror and white terror are rarely acknowledged. I haven't found any complete statistics related to this. But we know, that there are a lot of facts that can be included:

- Vietnam War
- [Korean War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_War) civilian deaths - 2–3 million
- Suharto's purge of [Indonesia in 1965](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2017/10/the-indonesia-documents-and-the-us-agenda/543534/) 1 million deaths.
- Operation [Condor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Condor) at least 60 000
- White terror in [Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Terror_(Russia)) up to 100 000
- Mass murders in  [Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesian_mass_killings_of_1965%E2%80%9366) up to 1 million deaths
- etc

The estimation of Communist terror includes every possible cause that's could think up, not just warfare. So that we can expand the list by disasters caused by Capitalism, for example we can easily interpret - [Partition of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_India) (Deaths - 200,000–2 million, displaced 10–20 million) or [disaster in Bhopal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhopal_disaster) (deaths - 16 000, injured - 500 000)  as Capitalism victims.

Of course my examples are not objective, this work should be done by experts. It is just that what could be included in the list, so that you can understand better that I mean.

Are their researches of Capitalism victims, which includes all this cases in the one place? And what they estimate? This is not the question of who killed more, though. I want to understand that the researches are made in this area, if any.

Comment: What has the partition of India to do with capitalism? I though the partition was about religion. Wouldn't that be more like religious terror then?

Comment: We can consider it as a mistake of Capitalism countries. Like Great Chinese Famine (1958-1961) [is included in the list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_killings_under_communist_regimes).

Comment: In the same vein, White Movement does not have anything to do with сapitalism, and was partly associated with non-Bolshevik socialist movements such as Social-Revolutionaries. Looking at that list I wonder why French Revolution is not on it as a capitalistic insurgency.

Comment: @alamar I can mess up with Anti-Communist and Capitalism, but I think my question is clear

Comment: I strongly suggest re-titling "Capitalist" to "Anti-Communist".

Comment: This question mixes up capitalism and anti-communism, and they are two different things. There is capitalism in China, but China is not anti-communist. Fascist Italy was surely anti-communist, but not capitalist.

Comment: The list of Communist terror (which I refer to) includes not only anti-capitalist terror. So I prefer to remove anti-communism just for consistency. Of course my examples are not objective, this work should be done by experts. It is just that what could be included in the list, so that you can understand better that I mean.

Comment: I think OP is right to phrase it like this, this is a question asked as a mirror to claims of mass crimes due to "Communism", with a ridiculously expansive definition of the term and of what it's responsible for. @alamar the french revolution overthrew the nobility and put the bourgeois in their place, so that may be one of the most legitimate examples of a (pro-)capitalist insurgency.

Comment: @Gouvernathor Well the existence of "communist" (and capitalist at the same time) China does pose a problem when defining mass crimes of communism. Should we count e.g. Uyghur reeducation camps as communism crimes or capitalism crimes? It's so hard to define.

Comment: @alamar It is, of course, it is so true! But victimsofcommunism and dozens of researchers did this for communist terror, with its own sorting criteria.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138885/discussion-between-michau-and-gouvernathor).

Comment: It is difficult to define the Korean war, rather than only capitalist it is the beginning of the cold war where white and red terror together crushed those caught in between, so I don't think it should be part of the list. On the other hand you can put in the Iran-Contras story and other events in Central America.

Comment: Are you double-counting Suharto/Indonesia's 1M deaths?  And how are Vietnam/Korea solely Western-side fault, when it was a common battleground?  Anyway, given the lack of relevance of Communism nowadays and rather long timelines, this should probably be asked in SE.History.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this framing is that "Capitalistic terror" assumes that capitalism was the main driver of that "terror", as opposed to some finer ideology. I'm sure you can find some hardcore Marxists-Leninists who'd agree with this. It reminds me how the Soviets [and their allies of then, e.g. Poland] objected to any allusion to WW2 or Nazis in the UDHR preamble because they saw the Nazi as merely an expression of capitalism, so in their view the Nazi genocide had been perpetrated by capitalists. So (to bring in newer examples) Rwanda, Bosnia etc. are all "capitalist genocides" in such an approach.

Ref for the historical claims: the book [*Inherent Human Rights*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt3fhgfn).

And actually, [there is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Livre_noir_du_capitalisme) such a tally:

> Le livre noir du Capitalisme (The Black Book of Capitalism) is a 1998 French book published in reaction to The Black Book of Communism (1997). [...]
>
> An appendix provides an incomplete list of 20th-century death-tolls which editor Gilles Perrault attributes to the capitalist system. The list includes certain death-tolls covering the two World Wars, colonial wars, anticommunist campaigns and repressions, ethnic conflicts, and victims of famines or malnutrition; bringing the incomplete total to 100 million deaths attributed to capitalism in the 20th century.

FWTW, the author [appears](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilles_Perrault#Engagements_politiques) to have been a self-declared communist.

Comment: Yes, the work the OP asks about makes the same kind of overreaching consideration as "victims of communism" or other similar organizations or work. Compared to these claims, the soviet ones you're referring to make real sense.

Comment: This is the appendix mentioned in the quote: https://web.archive.org/web/20080416085106/http://www.lescommunistes.org/spip.php?article29

Comment: @michau: as I suspected, everything is included, Rwanda, Bosnia etc.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, I don't think this exist - at least the way you described it, as research done seriously by teams of experts - nor would it likely see the light of day.

People who would want to do that would be critical of capitalism and therefore would necessarily see the nonsense in what you're referring to, the ridiculously expansive scope which they claim "communist crimes" cover. So, would they waste time and efforts doing a bad-faith research just to make a *reductio ad absurdum* argument ? Unlikely. Would they afford the necessary means to finance that research, travel to the places things happened, get the required manpower ? Without the financial support organizations like victimsofcommunism have at their disposal, also unlikely.

There could be an effort in that direction from countries declaring themselves as Communist or Socialist (China, Viet-Nam) to cast a bad light on the west. But it would require their international relationship strategy to be consistent with that at the same moment, which is not currently the case, as they're mostly open to capitalist investments and ventures.

Comment: I think people working in history and political science departments e.g. in China have both the financial resources and ideological motivation to produce such a list, as it would mostly put Western countries in bad light.

Comment: That could be true, I'm adding it to my answer.